# Using termfreq as a function query

Tags: solr

I'm working on an autocomplete functionality in Sol4, and I'm wondering if I can use termfreq in the filter query.  My query looks like this:

```
http://example.com/autocomplete/?q=ful&start=0&rows=5&&fl=Location,freq:termfreq(textng,'ful')
```

and returns:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="18" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="Location">Fullerton, CA</str>
<int name="freq">1</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="Location">Fulton, NY</str>
<int name="freq">1</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="Location">Fultondale, AL</str>
<int name="freq">1</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="Location">Cal State University Fullerton</str>
<int name="freq">1</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="Location">Full Sail Real World Education</str>
<int name="freq">1</int>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

I'd like to be able to do something like `fq:termfreq(textng,'ful'):1`.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fq={!frange l=1 u=10}termfreq(Location,'ful')
```

does it

There is some weird syntax placement with the "(" before fq= when combining it with OR:

```
(fq={!frange l=1 u=10}termfreq(textng,'ful') OR {!frange l=1 u=10}termfreq(textng,'county'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the questions n ofcourse solution dhysong!!!
I think it should be fl instead of fq.
Following query worked for me correctly. It gives me the total count of records having untitled word.
fl=count:totaltermfreq(title, 'untitled')
However this is not working with suggest. I'm trying like /suggest?spellcheck.q=india&fl=count:totaltermfreq(title, 'untitled'), title  Do you have any idea?